# How do I display a grouped graph using a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, plotly

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

df = pd.read_csv("final_spreadsheet.csv")

barchart = px.bar(
    data_frame = df,
    x = "Post-Lockdown Period (May - September)",
    y = "Post-Lockdown Period (May - September)",
    color = "Peak-Lockdown Period (March-May)",
    opacity = 0.9,
    orientation ="v",
    barmode = 'relative',
)
pio.show(barchart)
```

I want the x axis to be the different behavioral variables and for each behavioral variable I want there to be two bars one for peak pandemic and one for post pandemic. I also want the y axis to just be the values of each

This is my current attempt but no graphs appear. Attached is also a picture of the CSV file in excel form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plotly.express you can create a grouped bar chart by passing a list of the two variables you want to group together in the argument y. In your case, you'll want to pass the argument `y = ['Peak-Lockdown Period (March-May)','Post-Lockdown Period (May-September)']` as well as the argument `barmode = 'grouped'` to `px.bar`. I created a sample DataFrame to illustrate:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

# df = pd.read_csv("final_spreadsheet.csv")

## create example DataFrame similar to yours
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Behavioral': list('ABCD'),
    'Peak-Lockdown Period (March-May)': [76.7,26.12,0,2.94],
    'Post-Lockdown Period (May-September)': [77.32,26.38,0,3.36]
})


barchart = px.bar(
    data_frame = df,
    x = 'Behavioral',
    y = ['Peak-Lockdown Period (March-May)','Post-Lockdown Period (May-September)'],
    # color = "Peak-Lockdown Period (March-May)",
    opacity = 0.9,
    orientation ="v",
    barmode = 'group',
)

pio.show(barchart)
```

EDIT: you can accomplish the same thing using plotly.graph_objects:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='Peak-Lockdown Period (March-May)', x=df['Behavioral'].values, y=df['Peak-Lockdown Period (March-May)'].values),
    go.Bar(name='Post-Lockdown Period (May-September)', x=df['Behavioral'].values, y=df['Post-Lockdown Period (May-September)'].values),
])
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this with my dataframe but it gives me the error "ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument y is 2, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['Behavioral Variables'] is 27"

Comment: What version of plotly are you running? I am using v5.4.0

Comment: @William Shen if for some reason you're having trouble running my code using plotly.express, I have included an answer using plotly.graph_objects that should hopefully work for you

Comment: Ah thanks I figured out the issue i was missing a space on my code in Post-Lockdown Period (May-September). Your answer was very helpful, much appreciated